# Python sorted() function not working the way it should

Tags: python, list, lambda, nested, sorting

Basically I have a nested list that I am trying to sort through the 1'st index
I copied the way that the python howto says how to do it but it doesn't seem to work and I don't understand why:

code from the website:

```
>>> student_tuples = [
    ('john', 'A', 15),
    ('jane', 'B', 12),
    ('dave', 'B', 10),
    ]
>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])   # sort by age
    [('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

My code:

```
def print_scores(self):
    try:
        #opening txt and reading data then breaking data into list separated by "-"
        f = open(appdata + "scores.txt", "r")
        fo = f.read()
        f.close()
        userlist = fo.split('\n')
        sheet_list = []
        for user in userlist:
            sheet = user.split('-')
            if len(sheet) != 2:
                continue
            sheet_list.append(sheet)
        sorted(sheet_list, key = lambda ele : ele[1]) #HERE IS THE COPIED PART!
        if len(sheet_list) > 20: # only top 20 scores are printed
            sheet_list = sheet_list[len(sheet_list) - 21 :len(sheet_list) - 1]
       #prints scores in a nice table
        print "name          score"
        for user in sheet_list:
            try:
                name = user[0]
                score = user[1]
                size = len(name)
                for x in range(0,14):
                    if x > size - 1:
                        sys.stdout.write(" ")
                    else:
                        sys.stdout.write(name[x])
                sys.stdout.write(score + "\n")
            except:
                print ""


    except:
         print "no scores to be displayed!"
```

The bug is that the resulting printed list is exactly like how it was in the txt as if the sorting function didn't do anything!

Example:

Data in txt file:

```
Jerry-1284
Tom-264
Barry-205
omgwtfbbqhaxomgsss-209
Giraffe-1227
```

What's printed:

```
Name          Score
Jerry         1284
Tom           264
Barry         205
omgstfbbqhaxom209
Giraffe       1227
```

Comment: [First Rule of Programming: It's always your fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: @Brian Roach that was awesome!

Comment: @aitchnyu - Jeff Atwood is the co-founder of Stackoverflow. He's made some great blog posts over the years. That's one of my favorites.

Comment: @Brian Roach Yeah I see his and Joel Splosky's posts quoted a lot

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`sorted` returns a new list. If you want to modify the existing list, use

```
sheet_list.sort(key = lambda ele : ele[1])
```

Comment: still doesn't work completely, the list now is Giraffe,Jerry,Barry,omgw, and tom. It should be Jerry, Giraffe, Tom, omg, Barry.

Comment: @joseph: the sheet entries are strings.  It's sorting "alphabetically", not by the value of the number.  Try key=lambda ele: float(ele[1]), or convert them to numbers beforehand.