# How to sort a 2d Array by the first element, when a value for the index is 0

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

So I'm doing a practice problem where I'm trying to merge elements from a 2d array and return non-overlapping intervals.

I came up with the solution:

```py
def merge(self, intervals: List[List[int]]) -> List[List[int]]:
    sorted(intervals, key=lambda x: x[0])
    merged_intervals = []
    print(intervals)
    for interval in intervals:
        if not merged_intervals:
            merged_intervals.append(interval)
        else:
            if merged_intervals[-1][1] >= interval[0]:
                merged_intervals[-1][1] = interval[1]
            else:
                merged_intervals.append(interval)
    return merged_intervals
```

But I'm having an issue where if the test case is `[[1,4],[0,4]]` sorted() is returning the list in the same order. Am I misunderstanding how the lambda is used in the sorting algorithm here?

Comment: `sorted` does not do in-place sorting.  You would want to use `intervals.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])`.

Comment: or `intervals = sorted(intervals, key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python sorted() function not working the way it should](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767779/python-sorted-function-not-working-the-way-it-should)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between \`sorted(list)\` vs \`list.sort()\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442378/what-is-the-difference-between-sortedlist-vs-list-sort)